# Calling a rest api located on the remote client machine from my .Net web app?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, rest

I hope this isn't just a cross domain issue, I don't have much experience with AJAX calling restful API's.

I need to call a restful api running on the user's pc for local usb hardware from my corp .Net web app.  I have locations that have usb hardware that have locally installed web servers for a rest API to access the hardware.  I need to make the request from the corp web app to pass detailed identification information to the vendors gateway and wait for the response from the hardware.

Also, the remote offices are not on a corporate vpn, the call has to be from the asp web app running on the corp domain.

The vendor only has this interface and only have winform examples for local access.  They won't have an enterprise IP solution for another year.

Thanks in advance for any answers...I am hoping this is possible.

Comment: What is your question? Why isn't a Win Form example good enough to work out how to call the API from a web app? And how do you expect anyone to help if you don't provide the code?

Comment: I guess I asked the question too early, the winform example had a library interface that controlled the calls to the api, so I don't have any direct access to the calls.  I am just making some attempts via Postman to interact with the local web server and web service.  I do not do that much js or ajax so I was getting a feel of whether I can even do this or not.  I thought I would get an answer on the feasibility of this while I was starting to get into the details of the testing.

I currently only have the windows example and was just starting to work out js.  Sorry for the faux pas.

Comment: The question was whether I am able to call a localhost web service located on the client machine from my corporate web app run from our corporate servers.

Comment: Why would any of this involve JS or AJAX if it is possible to do it from Win Forms? Usually API calls are initiated on the *server side* from web applications unless there is some web UI component to it. You should pretty much be able to copy and paste the Windows Forms code and use it from a web app (except for the UI part).

Comment: The app is on the web server at the hosting site, the hardware is on the remote client machine and I have to access the local api via the browser, no access from the web server so I cannot make calls in the backend code on the server.  I may not be describing this right but I have no access from the web app located on the server to the client hardware on the local pc running my web app.

Comment: `calling a localhost web service located on the client machine from my corporate web app run from our corporate servers` - The REST API you are calling is running on localhost of the client's pc? You do realize that a network port needs to be open at the remote location in order to call the remote API from your web server, don't you? Unless you host an API or FTP site and have the remote client call your webserver to push the data to you. But again, if it works in Win Forms, there is no reason why it shouldn't work on a web app.

Comment: I do not have an app on the local machine, the user is in the browser running my web application and I need to access the hardware api from the remote pc's local web service.  I hope that clears the scenario up.  I am not running a windows application, only the sample app is running in windows.  I have to do this from a web app in the users browser to access the web service running in his local machine.

Comment: Okay, so you are calling a remote API and it is probably setup already to be called. Why does the API call have to originate from the browser? Is it reading some settings off of the client machine?

Comment: The client user's web service is not available externally, that is why I am assuming I need to use js to make the request.  Again, I may be wrong on this but that is the answer I am looking for.  Getting access from my app running in the client browser to access a resource on the clients machine from the browser.

Comment: I am one question behind...The API I need is installed on the client pc and not available from an outside address for my web app to call directly from the backend code on the server.  Or directly from an external call.

Comment: Again, I have not tried to do this and the vendor that made the API has never done this so I don't have the experience to know if this is even possible.  I posted to make sure I didn't get a day to two into trying things if this isn't even possible.

Comment: unless you can change firewall settings on the client machine and CORS settings inside client service as Night mentioned - I don't think it is possible - otherwise all websites could use all user's local services...

Comment: Okay. Now I understand. Is the client pc on the same LAN as the web server? If so, you can open up a port on the client pc so it can be called from the web server. That is the easy way. Otherwise, you will most likely need setup CORS to call localhost from your web app in the browser (not something I have worked with).

Comment: No, it is on it's own network, these are like franchises that have their own equipment and only remotely access our apps to run their office.  The company has not setup a corporate VPN for these offices.

I have not used CORS, if that is a possible solution, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I am so confused by this question...

Comment: It is not an ideal situation and I am trying to make it work the way the company wants to approach it.  The user's pc has: IE accessing web app, the usb device, web server running local (not public), web service to access device.  From the browser (web app) we need to make calls to the web service on the users machine and wait for the device to return results.  Never found anything on the web or forums about doing this kind of thing.  Hoping someone out there has done this.